# Как у становить pkg-config?

Tags: ssh

Эпопея с ZMQ продолжается.

```
sh -c "cd php-zmq && phpize && ./configure && make --silent && sudo make install"
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable 0MQ support... yes, shared
checking whether to enable CZMQ support... no
checking for pkg-config... /bin/pkg-config
checking libzmq installation... configure: error: Unable to find libzmq installation
```

Столкнулся с проблемой установки и требует установить pkg-config, скачал последний архив и распаковал в папку /root/pkg-config-0.29

тут такая проблема уже подымалась: https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/issues/2

Как установить правильно pkg-config не могу понять, только учусь всем примудростям...

Боюсь убить что-то... Помогите.

Comment: если ты не **уверен**, что тебе что-то нужно собирать из исходников, устанавливай это через пакетный менеджер своего дистрибутива.

Comment: вам заголовки `libzmq` надо установить, а не `pkg-config`. в *debian* и наследниках актуальное имя пакета с заголовками можно получить такой, например, командой: `$ apt-cache search libzmq dev`